# store new filename in mysql database verot class.upload.php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, upload

So I'm using http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_docs.htm?lang=en-GB to upload files to a mysql database. I'm a little new at mysql so please forgive my ignorance.

the below code snippet uploads the image, renames it properly, but stores the old file name in the database table.

```
include('class.upload.php');

$t = time();
$foo = new Upload($_FILES['receipt_u']);
if ($foo->uploaded) {
$foo->file_new_name_body = "img_$t";
$foo->file_max_size = '4194304'; //4MB
$foo->Process('pics'); 
}

$receipt_img =($_FILES['receipt_u']['name']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO product (receipt_u) VALUES (:rcpt)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':rcpt'=>$receipt_img));
    header("location: ../index.php");
```

There's actually a lot of data be passed into the database but I removed it for this purpose as this is the only thing giving me trouble.

Why is it posting the original file name into the database and not the new one?

Comment: "Why is it posting the original file name into the database and not the new one" bemuse that is exactly what your code says to do

Comment: Haha ok but how can i make it post the new name? @dagon

Comment: you have a variable with the new name in it, yet you give the query the old one, you work it out

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
echo $foo->file_dst_name;
```

your new code looks like:

```
$t = time();
$foo = new Upload($_FILES['receipt_u']);
if ($foo->uploaded) {
$foo->file_new_name_body = "img_$t";
$foo->file_max_size = '4194304'; //4MB
$foo->Process('pics'); 
}

//here its recipt image new 
$receipt_img = $foo->file_dst_name;

$sql = "INSERT INTO product (receipt_u) VALUES (:rcpt)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':rcpt'=>$receipt_img));
    header("location: ../index.php");
```